# Android AOSP13 Car emulator in bootloop after CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION permission request(priv-app)

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-source, android-13, android-automotive

My Android AOSP 13 Car emulator (sdk_car_x86_64-userdebug) gets stuck in a bootloop after a vendor application named **VehiclePropertyTest** requests the **CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION** permission. It is found that the Boot sequence could not complete because of priv-app permission allowlist issue throwing the following error:

```
02-01 19:28:30.814  2590  2590 W PackageManager: Privileged permission android.car.permission.CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION for package com.example.vehiclepropertytest (/system_ext/priv-app/VehiclePropertyTest) not in privapp-permissions allowlist
02-01 19:28:33.067  2590  2590 W PackageManager: Privileged permission android.car.permission.CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION for package com.example.vehiclepropertytest (/system_ext/priv-app/VehiclePropertyTest) not in privapp-permissions allowlist
02-01 19:28:33.068  2590  2590 E System  : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Signature|privileged permissions not in privapp-permissions allowlist: {com.example.vehiclepropertytest (/system_ext/priv-app/VehiclePropertyTest): android.car.permission.CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION}
02-01 19:28:33.068  2590  2590 E Zygote  : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Signature|privileged permissions not in privapp-permissions allowlist: {com.example.vehiclepropertytest (/system_ext/priv-app/VehiclePropertyTest): android.car.permission.CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION}
02-01 19:28:33.068  2590  2590 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Signature|privileged permissions not in privapp-permissions allowlist: {com.example.vehiclepropertytest (/system_ext/priv-app/VehiclePropertyTest): android.car.permission.CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION}
```

Created a vendor application called **VehiclePropertyTest**, which is a **priv-app** and uses the **CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION** for a vendor specific property (which was already added in aidl hal).

Added the following permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.car.permission.CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION"/>
```

**Troubleshooting Attempts:**

Added the CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION to permission allowlist by two ways:

1. Modified permission to *frameworks/base/data/etc/permissions/privapp-permissions-platform.xml* from [Android Documentation](https://source.android.com/docs/core/permissions/perms-allowlist)

   ```
   <privapp-permssions package="com.example.vehiclepropertytest">
        <permission name="android.car.permission.CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION"/>
   </privapp-permissions>
   ```
2. Creating a custom permission xml and added it to prebuilt_etc in appliction's Android.bp

***privapp-permission-vehiclepropertytest.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<permissions>
  <privapp-permissions package="com.example.vehiclepropertytest">
       <permission name="android.car.permission.CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION"/>
   </privapp-permissions>
</permissions>
```

***Android.bp***

```
prebuilt_etc {
   name: "privapp-permission-vehiclepropertytest",
   src: "privapp-permissions-vehiclepropertytest.xml",
   sub_dir: "permissions",
   filename_from_src: true,
}
```

then `required: ["privapp-permission-vehiclepropertytest"],` inside **android_app{}**

**Questions:**

1. How can I verify if the CAR_VENDOR_EXTENSION permission is correctly added to the allowlist?
2. Are there known conflicts or issues with this permission in AOSP 13?

Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

As described in [s.a.c document](https://source.android.com/docs/core/permissions/perms-allowlist), priv permissions allowlist should be located in product, vendor, or system partition's specified location. Please take a look document for more detail. (I assumed you build your emulator from source codes)

Comment: Yes I refered the documentation and it is found that the applicaton is located in system/priv-app directory and the permissions directory contains the privapp-permission-vehiclepropertytest.xml as well as the default privapp-permissions-platform.xml, which has all my permissions.